# decode Subject of mail using ImapX lib?

Tags: c#, email, gmail, email-client, imapx

I have problem when get Subject of mail.
Problem is: if subject is English it is can get good
but if subject is vietnamese (my language) it return null;

Answer (score 1):

```
string encoding = msg.HtmlBody.ContentType.Split('=')[1];

string decodedBody = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(msg.HtmlBody.TextData));
string decodedSubject = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(msg.Subject.Split('?')[3]));
```

Comment: This code only works for Base64 encoded strings. Quoted printable encoding can also be used, and it's quite frequent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the old ImapX library, I invite you to upgrade to [ImapX 2](http://imapx.codeplex.com/). It now supports automated decoding of subjects, file names and body content. The library is being constantly developed and supported. There is also sample code for all common operations.